# How do you use Observable.bindCallback()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

How do I use `Observable.bindCallback()` with a callback that returns 2 args, `callback(results, status)`? The example is with `google.maps.places` API below:

```
  const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  // service.nearbySearch(request, callback);


  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to do something like this:

```
const handleError = err=>console.error(error);

const nearbyAsObservable = Observable.bindCallback(service.nearbySearch)
nearbyAsObservable(request)
   .subscribe( 
     (results,status)=>{
       if (status!="OK") handleError(results);
       callback
     }
     , handleError
   )
```

but I am unsure about the following:

1) is the best practice to "throw" an error from the `next` handler and catch it in the `error` handler, or just call the method `handleError()`?

2) I am getting `Cannot read property 'nearbySearch' of undefined(…)` error. But when I call `const nearbyAsObservable = Observable.bindCallback( service.nearbySearch.bind(service) )` I get a TS error:

```
// const nearbyAsObservable = Observable.bindCallback(service.nearbySearch.bind(service) )
// nearbyAsObservable(request)
[ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
const nearbyAsObservable: () => Observable<{}>
```

**update** it looks like this hack will fix the TS error

```
const nearbyAsObservable : any = Observable.bindCallback(service.nearbySearch.bind(service) )
nearbyAsObservable(request)
   .subscribe( 
     (results,status)=>{
       if (status!="OK") handleError(results);
       callback
     }
     , handleError
   )
```

but the `next` handler complains if I give it a `(result, status)=>void`

3) how do I transform the Observable return from `Observable<[result, status]>` to `Observable<PlaceResult[]>`?

Comment: Try `Observable.bindCallback(service.nearbySearch.bind(service))`

Comment: How do you know you're not handling errors correctly?

Comment: I answered another question using `bindCallback` with the same API you are using, but I can no longer find it. I can only assume that user's account was deleted. It'll take a little while to remember the details.

Comment: I think I found the answer: use a selector function in the bindCallback()!  I'll post the complete answer below.

Comment: Yep, that's it. You need to use a selector to map the arguments received in the callback to an array or an object and that becomes the type of the observable that's returned by the bound function.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is the following:

1) bind the scope to your callback, as necessary (see comment)

2) if you bind the scope, then use `let nearbyAsObservable : any;` to fix a TS bug [how do I use `Observable.bindCallback()` with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524472/how-do-i-use-observable-bindcallback-with-typescript)

3) use a `selector` function in `Observable.bindCallback()` to map multiple return args into a single response for the `subscribe` function, and also to throw errors.  [How do I use the RXJS selector function in the Observable.bindCallback method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275226/how-do-i-use-the-rxjs-selector-function-in-the-observable-bindcallback-method)

```
let nearbyPlaces = function(position: google.maps.LatLng) : Observable<google.maps.places.PlaceResult[]> {  
  const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)
  // 1) bind scope
  const nearbySearchCallback = service.nearbySearch.bind(service)

  let nearbyAsObservable : any;
  // 2) type any fixes: 
  //    [ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. 
  //    const nearbyAsObservable: () => Observable<{}>  

  nearbyAsObservable = Observable.bindCallback( 
    nearbySearchCallback        // with bound scope
    , (results, status) => {    // 3) selector function
        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) throw {status, results};
        return results  
      }
  );
  const placeRequest = {
    location: position,
    radius: 25,
    rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.PROMINENCE,
  }
  return nearbyAsObservable(placeRequest) as Observable<google.maps.places.PlaceResult[]>
}


// usage example:
nearbyPlaces(position).subscribe(
  (results:google.maps.places.PlaceResult[])=>console.log(results)
  , err=>console.error(err)
)
```

Comment: If you cast the `bind` result to `(request: PlaceSearchRequest, callback: (results: PlaceResult[], status: PlacesServiceStatus) => void) => void` it should play nice with TypeScript and the argument types should be inferred, but that is one long, ugly cast.